# Trying to use contextless navigation without a GetMaterialApp or Get.key, while opening a firebase notification

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation, flutter-getx

I faced this issue when firebase notification is received in system tray and user tap on the notification to open it. Then the app is crashed i got this error: You are trying to use contextless navigation without a GetMaterialApp or Get.key

Answer (score 0):

So after trying so many approaches, i've fixed this issue by adding a

```
return GetMaterialApp(
        getPages: pages,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        navigatorKey: Get.key,
        title: 'CRV',
        theme: ThemeData(colorScheme:
              ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: const Color(0xFF19A753)),
          useMaterial3: true,
        ),
        initialRoute: "/",
      );
```

> splash screen in my flutter application and in the main.dart, i added
> the initial route = "/' that belongs to splash screen.

**static const String routeName = "/";**

here's my pages screen look like:

```
 List<GetPage> pages = [
  GetPage(
      name: SplashScreen.routeName,
      page: () => const SplashScreen(),
      transition: Transition
          .fadeIn
      ),
    ]
```

in this way the contextless navigation issue is resolved and now i can open the notifications.